# How can I add linkable anchors to Markdown headers on my Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, links, html, javascript, tumblr-themes

I'd like Markdown headers, like thus,

```
### Important stuff!         ->    <h3>Important stuff!</h3>
```

to compile with HTML `id` properties, so they can be linked directly to:

```
### Important stuff!         ->    <h3 id='important-stuff'>Important stuff!</h3>
```

I can't find a configuration option on Tumblr to do this; and there seems to be no way to access the content of the `{Body}` through [Tumblr's theming system](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) (unsurprisingly, I suppose) ... can I do this without relying on JavaScript? And will the `id`'s even be anchor-linkable if I resort to adding them through JavaScript?

> **Edit:** (For completeness, a JavaScript solution that can be copy-pasted into a user's theme, if that's what is necessary, would be ideal.)

Comment: I'd recommend doing this outside of Tumblr and then posting to Tumblr

Comment: Definitely an option, @ZachSaucier, but … the obvious one, I suppose. It's not a real *solution*, as such. I'll leave this question open.